# Python file pull from SharePoint Online

Tags: python

I'm a beginner with Python and would appreciate any assistance you can provide.

I am attempting to pull a row from an Excel file located in SharePoint online and am getting this error -

```
line 25, in <module>
excel_file = io.BytesIO(file.download().content)
TypeError: File.download() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file_object'`
```

Here is the code

```
import io
import openpyxl
import docx
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

# SharePoint Online authentication information
site_url = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site"
username = "your-username@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com"
password = "your-password"

# Prompt user for row number to export
row_number = int(input("Enter row number to export: "))

# SharePoint Online file information
file_url = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/Shared%20Documents/Workbook.xlsx"

# Connect to SharePoint Online and get Excel file
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(site_url)
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password)
ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)
file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_url(file_url)

# Load Excel file and get row values
excel_file = io.BytesIO(file.download().content)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
row_values_1 = [cell.value for cell in ws[1]]
row_values_2 = [cell.value for cell in ws[row_number]]

# Load Word document and create a new table with the row values
doc = docx.Document('Document.docx')
table = doc.add_table(rows=2, cols=len(row_values_1), style='Table Grid')
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
for i, val in enumerate(row_values_1):
    hdr_cells[i].text = str(val)

for i, val in enumerate(row_values_2):
    row_cells = table.rows[1].cells
    row_cells[i].text = str(val)

# Save the modified Word document
doc.save('Document.docx')`
```

Thanks again!

Changed to this

```
# Load Excel file and get row values
excel_file = io.BytesIO()
file.download(excel_file)
excel_file.seek(0)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
row_values_1 = [cell.value for cell in ws[1]]
row_values_2 = [cell.value for cell in ws[row_number]]
```

But am now gettting -

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Documents/ExtoWordtablespv2.py", line 28, in 
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 344, in load_workbook
reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 123, in **init**
self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 95, in _validate_archive
archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 1267, in **init**
self._RealGetContents()
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 1334, in _RealGetContents
raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file